# SFTP Issue on ColdFusion 2016

Tags: coldfusion, cfftp

We recently migrated our applications from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 2016. One of our applications SFTPs files using cfftp tag.

We noticed that CFFTP tag with ColdFusion 2016 no longer works. We worked with our internal IT team and the remote SFTP server team to resolve all issues with firewall and when we connect with WINSCP from our end, we were able to successfully connect to the remote server but when we use CFFTP from ColdFusion 2016, it seems stuck in the CFFTP tag. It does not even time out.

Initially we thought it's the same code as CF9 and since CFFTP worked in CF9, it should work in CF 2016 but it did not. Later we realized that some of the tags were deprecated and we corrected that and ran the tests. But our efforts were in vain.

We get this error message in the FTP log:
"Information","ajp-nio-8016-exec-1","06/20/18","14:06:00","","Starting FTP request {action='open'}"

We used the below code to connect:

```
<cfftp action = "open"
        connection = "myConnection1"
        fingerprint="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll:mm:nn:oo"
        passive="yes"
        password="xxxxx"
        port="22"
        secure = "yes"
        server = "1.1.1.1"  
        stopOnError = "yes" 
        timeout="30"
        username = "xyz">
```

We are currently stuck unable to SFTP through ColdFusion.

Please assist.

KP

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was a known bug that was fixed in ColdFusion 2016 (you can use the updater tool). More specifically it was an outdated jar file. Other versions of ColdFusion have fixed this by copying the updated jar file in CF2016 and placing it in the bin folder of the older CF version.

Try running the CF updater to see if it fixes your issue. If it doesn't, make sure you are using an updated JRE (there are specific fixes that won't take affect unless you are running a more recent 1.8 JRE).

Comment: Hello Jeff  - Thanks for your response. As i mentioned in my post, we are already using ColdFusion 2016 and the issue is on ColdFusion 2016. The server has all the updates (v 6).

Comment: Just to isolate the issue, I installed ColdFusion 2016 Developer version on AWS windows instance (using my company's AWS account as the client did not provide us the access to the environments), I installed a SFTP server on another AWS instance. I used the CFFTP tag and it worked. This leads me to believe that its not CFFTP tag and it seems to me like firewall issue but again, WINSCP from the server works so its puzzling.

Comment: What JRE version are you using?

Comment: Here is the info: Version 2016, 0, 06, 308055
Tomcat Version 8.5.28.0
Java Version 1.8.0_161
OpenSSL Version 1.0.2n

Comment: Yeah, that's fairly recent and shouldn't be an issue (thanks for the info). I'm guessing you're right and it's a firewall issue (either software or hardware firewall).

Comment: So we tried to connect to the SFTP server using WINSCP and it works. It is the code / CF 2016 Server that is not allowing the connection to go through.